# Creating a list of means from a dictionary of Samples

Tags: python, loops, statistics

I created a dictionary of samples (exponential distributions) using a loop.

```
def sampleexp():
  samples = {}
  for i in range(100,10100,100):
    samples[i] = np.random.exponential(scale= 1/1.2, size= i)
  return samples 

samples = sampleexp()
samples[] #Call using sample size here
```

The code above produces a dictionary of each sample, formatted as numpy arrays. What Im trying to do below is calculate the mean of each sample from the dictionary above and place them into a simple array, which I will then use to calculate the population mean and plot a histogram of all the values.

```
def samplemeans():
  means = []
  for i in range (1,i,100):
    means[i] = np.mean(samples[i] for i in samples)
  return means

samplemeanarray= samplemeans()
```

I keep getting an error that says "local variable i was referenced before assignment". I'm sure there's a simple fix I'm missing.

Comment: What are you expecting from `range(1,i,100)`?

Comment: I figured that was probably where I went wrong. Im an extreme beginner so Im still getting used to syntax/the language in general. My reasoning is that I have a hundred different samples, and was hoping the calculate the mean 100 times. Im guessing I did that incredibly wrong

Answer (score 0):

```
def samplemeans():
  means = []
  for i in range (1,i,100):
                    ^
```

This instance of `i` *must* have a value when you try to initialize the `for` loop controls.  You didn't give it a value, so there's a run-time error.

Also, your confusion between the two `i` uses on the line should be fixed.  Since we don't know what you're trying to do with this construct, we can't help much.

Perhaps you wanted to repeat the loop 100 times?

```
for i in range(100):
```

does the job.  Review your educational materials on `for` loops, so you can *think* in this unit.

Comment: Im trying to calculate the mean of every array produced by the first block of code (samples[]) and place those values into a new list. I was trying to follow the same coding scheme as the dictionary I created.

Comment: Then do so.  Do not change the loop control values?

Comment: I tried your initial code suggestion and ended up with another error.

def samplemeans():
  list = []
  for i in range (100):
    list[i] = list.append(np.mean(samples[i] for i in samples))
  return means

samplemeanarray = samplemeans()

TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'generator' and 'int'

Comment: Yup; this is two more errors, independent of the one you asked about, and each other.  StackOverflow handles one issue per question; we sometimes do not look beyond the one you posted.  I strongly recommend you back up and use incremental programming: write a couple of lines of code, or an expression.  Test it; make *sure* you know how it works, and that it does what you want.  Only then do you move forward.

Your problem here is that you've coded several layers of processing with multiple misunderstandings of how to use each one.  Until you get them *all* fixed at once, you get problems.

Comment: See this lovely [debug](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) blog for help.
To start, insert a couple of useful `print` statements to examine your variables.  For instance, start with `for i in samples: print(i, samples[i])`  I am highly confident that this will show you a conceptual error -- one that is answered many places on this channel, under "index out of range".

Answer (score -1):

The second argument of range() is the upper bound to iterate to.
The third argument to range() is the step size.

You can't use the current value as upper bound, that's why you get that error.

`i` hasn't been set yet when you call range().

Comment: Your middle statement is incorrect.  If `i` were set before hitting the `for` statement, the loop would use that value for the loop controls and execute per Python definition.  Try it!  `i = 5; for i in range(1, i): print(i)`

Comment: It is perfectly correct for OP's code. I explain why in the last statement.